# How to add plugins in android +phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

can you please provide some steps how to add plugin in android using phonegap .
I do like this .
1) Add this line in plugin.xml 
 
add java  file source folder.
javascript file on js folder.

i am using this plugin
https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap/tree/master/assets

Comment: it must be enough. Then you write javascript code to use the plugin. But the plugin you want to use is pretty old, might have compatibility issues with current cordova releases.

Comment: please provide new one ..

Comment: i need to add web socket plugin..with example

Comment: It might not just be a case of updating the plugin - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064815/phonegap-websocket-plugin-with-android-version-4-0-3-not-working?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

You can check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684711/installation-of-plugincom-simonmacdonald-telephonenumber-in-phonegap-app), which i have also same problem to add plugin. I have also seen [this tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/), this was also helpful for me.