# Issue with phonegap/cordova android websocket plugin - onmessage is not called

Tags: android, cordova, websocket, phonegap-plugins

I am using this plugin: https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket/*.

Unfortunately, onmessage is not called when we receive a message.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + window.location.host + "" + "/my/socket");

ws.onopen = function() {
   console.log("wsStatus Connected to WebSocket server!"); 
};

ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
};
```

This is never called - which is bizarre because onopen *is* called. Is there anything specific I need to do/check - add a listener? I looked in the [example code for the plugin](https://bitbucket.org/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket-demo/src/e6a874f8280900c0273af552c4970232d27c38b5/client/www/index.html?at=master) and see the event `ping` is used rather than `onmessage`.

* having tried most of the options here: [Phonegap websocket plugin with android version >4.0.3 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064815/phonegap-websocket-plugin-with-android-version-4-0-3-not-working#comment26426604_17064815) and finding this is the only one which appears to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since websocket doesnt support android<4.2, the above code fails.. you should try cross browser socket supported with fallback mode included, **socket.io**
[link](http://socket.io)

Comment: This would require changes on the server though surely?

Comment: OK, thanks. Is there any way to have phonegap plugin for websockets on android, without making changes to the server? I thought that by using a plugin we could do this.

Comment: There are plugins for websocket, but not so stable and flexible as socket.io

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! Can you recommend any which work? I have looked at/implemented so many it's becoming frustrating to follow instructions which simply don't have the advertised effect

Comment: try https://github.com/mkuklis/phonegap-websocket  or https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap

Comment: Thanks - have you actually used these or just seen them on Google? I have exactly the same problem with both, I can connect, and appear to send messages (I can run it in the browser fine) but still, I get no onmessage event

Comment: I ve used 1 st but no use,  thats y I switched to socket io